# Wrong output element of ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

i want to print element from arraylist, but i'm getting wrong output (.A@15db9742)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
class A {
int aa;
A(int x) { 
    aa=x;
}   
}
public class test{
public static void main(String[] args){
    A aa = new A(1);
    A ab = new A(2);
    A ac = new A(3);
ArrayList<A> lista = new ArrayList<A>(3);
lista.add(aa);
lista.add(ab);
lista.add(ac);
System.out.println(lista.get(0)); }
```

Comment: What is the expected output? And what is the output you are getting?

Comment: You should indent your code properly if you are asking people to try and read it.

Comment: What do you mean by 'wrong output' ?

Comment: It is hard to tell what you expect, but maybe this is helpful: [How do I print my Java object without getting “SomeType@2f92e0f4”?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29140402/how-do-i-print-my-java-object-without-getting-sometype2f92e0f4)

Comment: Override `toString` method in class `A`

Comment: @Simze i'm expecting to get value of first element of an arraylist (1), and i'm getting "<projectname>.A@15db9742"

Comment: See @Jesper linked question.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your code is supposed to return 1, your issue lies in that your class A doesn't include a toString method

heres some info on toString: [toString](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString())

insert this method into class A:

```
public String toString() {
    return Integer.toString(aa);
}
```

for future reference, try to style your code slightly more clearly so that others could read what you're trying to do

ex:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

class A {
    int aa;

    A(int x) {
        aa=x;
    }
}

public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A aa = new A(1);
        A ab = new A(2);
        A ac = new A(3);
        ArrayList<A> lista = new ArrayList<A>(3);
        lista.add(aa);
        lista.add(ab);
        lista.add(ac);
        System.out.println(lista.get(0));
    }
}
```

good luck :D

Answer (score 0):

You must override `toString` method in class `A`:

```
public String toString() { 
return "aa: " + this.aa;
}
```

Comment: thanks. it's working now.